# Order By Condition For ResultSet Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have one tabel 'cms'  when i call fetchAll() function which fetch all data fetch data with order by id desc means i want to pass orderby condition with fetchAll() function.

My Cms.php page is:

```
    <?php
    namespace Front\Model;
    use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;

    class Cms extends AbstractTableGateway {

        public function __construct($adapter) {
            $this->table = 'cms';
            $this->adapter = $adapter;
        } 
        public function fetchAll($id) {
               return $this->select();
        }
        public function getCmsContent($id){
            $id  = (int) $id;
            $rowset = $this->select(array('id'=>$id));
            if (!$row = $rowset->current()){
                throw new \Exception ('Row not found');
            }
            return $row;
        }
    }
```

My Controller is :FrontController.php is:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Front\Model\Cms;
use Front\Model\Setting;
use Front\Model\Slider;
class FrontController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {   

        return        array('cms_data'=>$this->getCms()->fetchAll('1'));             
    }

    public function getCms(){
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Front\Model\Cms');
    }

}
```

My Model is:

```
namespace Front;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array('Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' =>
            array('namespaces' =>
                array(__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(

                'Front\Model\Cms' =>  function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table     = new \Front\Model\Cms($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },

            ),
        );
    }
}
?>
```

My View:index.php Page is:

```
 <?php print_R($cms_data); ?>
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `order by` anywhere.

Comment: I want to use order by,but i dont know how to use it.so please help me to use order by.

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html):

```
$select = new Select;
$select->order('id DESC'); // produces 'id' DESC

$select = new Select;
$select->order('id DESC')
     ->order('name ASC, age DESC'); // produces 'id' DESC, 'name' ASC, 'age' DESC

$select = new Select;
$select->order(array('name ASC', 'age DESC')); // produces 'name' ASC, 'age' DESC
```

The same method `order` applies to table gateway.

Comment: i used public function fetchAll($id) { $select = new Select;
      $select->order('name DESC');
               return $this->select();
        }  Fatal error: Class 'Front\Model\Select' not found in E:\wamp\www\staes\module\front\src\Front\Model\cms.php on line 43

Comment: use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

Comment: @Akonf thanks for your reply.i used Zend\Db\Sql\Select so its remove fatal error,but in my model function fetchAll cant take order . may be i written function fetchAll is like something wrong, but i cant fetch it.Please help to solve it.